# Will the EM field radius of 10 x 20 Amp wires be smaller than a single 200 Amp wire?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-current, electrical-engineering

Not sure how the radius is determined but Will 10X20amps wires in one conduit(meaning they are together) EMF radius be smaller than 1X200amps wire?

I'm having a real life question on this:  I can run $10$ lines of $20$-Amp in my attic, or just a $200$-Amp line on my attic (let's say they are fully 100% loaded).  Which one is safer for me? Do 10 smaller current lines, when together in one conduit, produce an EMF radius which is smaller than the 200 Amp? Is it safer for people underneath the attic?

Answer (score 0):

Proximity to a 200A wire is not unsafe due to its magnetic field; the
electric field is dealt with by a suitable insulation layer, and
by sheathing (like, a conduit).

The most important safety issue with a multiplicity of lines in
a conduit is the cooling: all that insulation between the wires
prevents air circulation, so there are safe limits on how
many wires of a given insulation rating and size can fit into a conduit.

Answer (score 0):

By code you will need a (200amp )breaker,  off your existing (main) panel, assuming it has the breaker space, and capacity and a subpanel in the attic with a breaker for each load bearing (10)circuit you run,  in your case ten breakers (200a10-a) or any combo of 200amp.
Ten individual circuit runs from the main would require breaker space in the main panel. 
Either way your concern for EMR effects to occupants below is not an issue.